# jQuery and live webcam video streaming

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video-streaming, html5-video

I'm trying to build application where people can have their own rooms and stream video from webcam, so other people can see them. I was trying approach with red5, but I can't integrate it with php so I'm trying with jquery now. So far I've tried those three plugins:

1. http://www.scriptcam.com/docs.cfm and it's the closest to what I want ( it has one-to-many videochat ) but You can only have 5 viewers.
2. http://jqueryvideo-player.com someone said that it has an option to stream a video from webcam but I haven't found that on docs.
3. https://github.com/infusion/jQuery-webcam but I can't find a way to allow many people to see my webcam view.

and I know there's a lot more, but neither of them allow broadcasting. Is there any way to do this with jquery?

EDIT: I was also trying with html5 ( http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/ for example ) but I always get an error that "getUserMedia() is not supported on Your browser". I've tried that on Opera 18.0 and on Chrome 32.0.1700.102 m so I don't know why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Using the getUserMedia() API is a good native alternative assuming the browsers you will be targeting support it. Look here: http://caniuse.com/#feat=stream. You might also want to give some thought into WebRTC. Its still being developed, but this technology seems to be catching a lot of attention. Posting code snippets will also better help understand your question.

Comment: well, actually right now there is no code at all. All I can provide is page with the exact same functionality which I want to provide, but..well, it's almost porn-site so I think I can't link it in here. I thought that my question is quite clear.. Also - I've installed Opera 20 and still get the same error.