# Publishing video with webcam from browser

Tags: jquery, html, webcam, rtmp, live-streaming

Нallo, 
is it possible to publish live-stream from webcam to rtmp server without special soft, only by using flash?

I want to make teach service, where user can translate his own lesson to big audience with few webcams

Where have i dig?)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are better off using an already existing service such as livestream.com, or even YouTube's live feature (check this link out http://www.streamingmedia.com/Articles/Editorial/Featured-Articles/How-to-Stream-Live-Video-With-YouTube-94030.aspx)

This is also an already existing question I found on Stack Overflow regarding a similar situation:
[jQuery and live webcam video streaming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22894567/jquery-and-live-webcam-video-streaming)

This website offers a solution with flash fallback for capturing webcam video in-browser:
http://www.xarg.org/project/jquery-webcam-plugin/

This was posted with the tags jquery and html, not flash, so it is a little unclear if you are looking for a flash-based solution, or a jquery/html solution, but hopefully you will find some of these resources useful.